# Is it possible to specify the default value of the ClassID registry key created by regasm?

Tags: .net, com-interop

When using regasm to register an assembly for COM interop, one of things it does is create a HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{000…000} registry key with a default value of the ProgId of the COM class (See MSDN article [Registering Assemblies with COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h627s4zy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)).

Is it possible to specify the string that regasm sets as the default value of the key? I.e. Give it a more meaningful name?

For example:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{000…000}\Default = "Descriptive name for my really useful class"

instead of:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{000…000}\Default = "An.Obscure.Prog.Id"

I guess it would be possible to tweak the registry values after regasm has set them, but it would be easier if I could just persuade regasm to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both question and answer have it wrong.  There are three names involved here:

1. The ClassId or GUID, with the familiar format, e.g. "{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}"
2. The ProgId or programmatic name, which should be formatted as Vendor.Component.Version (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911706.aspx) - e.g. "Word.Document.12"
3. The human readable name - this is the name that is generally displayed in a list of COM components (like the add reference/COM dialog in VS or Insert -> Object menus in OLE apps), e.g. "Microsoft Word Document"

The corresponding entries in the registry are:

```
CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ClassId @= "Human readable name"
CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ClassId\ProgId @= "ProgId"
CLASSES_ROOT\ProgId @= "Human readable name"
CLASSES_ROOT\ProgId\CLSID @= "ClassId"
```

See your own registry for some examples.

If you reflect on regasm.exe, you'll see that it uses Type.FullName as the human readable name, always.  This is a pain in the ass because it means you have to set the HRN using a com registration hook.  It would have been pretty easy for them to look up the DisplayName attribute, for example, and use this instead.  Anyway, here's a helper function that sets the HRN entries.  Call it from your registration hook.

For more details on COM registration hooks see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comregisterfunctionattribute.aspx

```
public static void SetHumanReadableName(Type t, string humanReadableName)
{
    var classKeyName = string.Format(@"CLSID\{{{0}}}", t.GUID);
    var classKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(classKeyName, true);
    if (classKey == null)
        return;
    classKey.SetValue(string.Empty, humanReadableName);
    // if it has a progid set the HRN on the progid entry too
    foreach (ProgIdAttribute progId in t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProgIdAttribute), false))
    {
        var progIdKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(progId.Value, true);
        if (progIdKey != null)
            progIdKey.SetValue(string.Empty, humanReadableName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your class which has RegisterClass() function to register itself for COM Interop there are several Attrubutes you need to add

```
[ProgId("Descriptive name for my really useful class")]
[Guid("000000-23FD-4F6F-8B50-0000000")]
```

in Guid attribute there is guid which goes to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID

in ProgID is the meaningful name you want.

Acctually it's recommented to have ProgID as namespace + class name so you'd better to rename your class (and) project to more meaningful name.